# D3 Edge Bundling generates edge full length of svg

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js, svg

I have been working on some plots that use as their foundation this beautiful snippet: [non-hierarchical radial outlay with edge bundling](http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5450007), adding hover-overs and other decorations. I've noticed, however, that when the snippet is fed certain json files, it generates edges that span the full height (or width) of the svg to which the edges are appended. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dduhaime/yo7a8t1d/5/) replicates the problem in Chrome.

In this fiddle, the edge between Arthur and Blanche spans the full length of the svg, while I would expect the edge to simply link Arthur and Blanche. A friend suggested that the JSON could be different for this edge, but it's consistent with the rest of the JSON. (The Arthur-Blanche JSON is represented in the second hash table below):

```
{
  source: 5,
  target: 4,
  value: 1
},
{
  source: 5,
  target: 6,
  value: 5
},
{
  source: 5,
  target: 7,
  value: 2
},
```

Does anyone know why this edge is displayed across the full span of the SVG?

I imagine I could hack the path to remove edge segments that fall outside of the main circle's radius, but I'm eager to understand what's causing this strange behavior. I would be very grateful for any assistance others can offer on this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to delve deep into this to give you the solution here it is :)

Instead of the line function

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Make the condition that the y never goes beyond the diameter

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {if(d.x<0 || d.x > diameter) {d.x=diameter} return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) {if(d.y<0 || d.y > diameter) {d.y=diameter} return d.y; });
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yo7a8t1d/14/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Cyril! Unfortunately, other JSON fed to your changed fiddle still produces the problem :/ Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yo7a8t1d/10/ I've loaded multiple JSON files in the same format into https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime-shakespeare/folger-gender/ + {fileName} + .json where fileName refers to any of these values: 1H4 AYL H5 Lr Per TN WT 1H6 Ado H8 MM R2 TNK Wiv 2H4 Ant Ham MND R3 Tim 2H6 Cor JC MV Rom Tit 3H6 Cym Jn Mac Shr Tmp AWW Err LLL Oth TGV Tro

Comment: Updated my answer above and fiddle this should NAIL it LOL :)

Comment: Thanks again @Cyril! I think this gets closer, but when I feed in `"https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime-shakespeare/folger-gender/Tit.json"` I still get the svg-spanning lines. Do you have any notion as to why that might be?

Comment: yes because you have to do the same for x  as well that is restrict it within 500 radius. That was the issue in this new JSOn updated my answer and fiddle. Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: Thanks @Cyril. This rectifies the longer lines in files like Tit.json, but I'm still trying to figure out what's making those lines overrun the nodes in the first place. (You can see that this is initially so in your snippet by examining the edges upon page load). Do you have a sense what's causing those lines to be so long in the first place?

Comment: Till the far distance i could debug it was because of the force layout which returned a very high  d.y and d.x for those special nodes...which is actually the in build logic of d3...if you find teh reason do apprise me please :)